# Modify the Wordpress URL

Tags: urls

I want to find a solution for the following problem:

On my website, I want to show a specific content on a certain page, e.g.: http://mysite.de/locations/location-xyz

locations is wordpress page
location-xyz is a special location and should be replaceable with any other location (location-abc, location-sdf, uvw-location -> the exact slug of a location).

But I don't want do create a site for every single location. I've created a template file for the locations page and on this page I want to display information about the given location. If no location is given, I want to show the content of the locations page.

It is clear to me, that I could easy access the location wirth the following solution: http://mysite.de/locations/?location=location-xyz. But that's not the way I want to do it.

The problem is, that Wordpress automticlly tries to find the page "location-xyz".

Is there any possiblity to access the url-parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: Could this be a case for a custom post type of `locations`, with `locations-xyz`, `locations-abc` etc being categories?

Comment: Is location a custom post type or a custom taxonomy term? Or a page? I would suggest a CPT or taxonomy instead, most likely a CPT. I'd also either avoid having a page called "locations", or call the page "locations" and use "location/locationxyz" as the URL structure, as it will greatly simplify your task

Comment: locations is a page. And location-xyz etc. are not all different categories. All locations could belong to a category (e.g. "places" or "locations"). I want to build it up like an post (e.g. http://mysite.de/category-a/my-first-post). replace "category-a" with "locations" and "my-first-post" with "location-xyz". I haven't thougth about the post-type of my locations yet, but it won't be a page or a post..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to taker a look at [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) or [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). Then to test, install a plugin called [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), it'll help you show you if your rules are conflicting.